# You must first connect to a database to use Browser Sync in neo4j

Tags: kubernetes, installation, neo4j, yaml, cluster-computing

i deployed the neo4j in kubernetes, so when i tried to acess http://:7474/ it show me this error( ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver.), hoe can i solve it?

Comment: You should provide a full stack trace and steps on how to reproduce the issue (e.g. how did you deployed the neo4j in Kubernetes etc).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment a single line inside `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

The issue is well described [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/)

If you're using `Neo4j Helm` instead of `neo4j.conf` you will have `values.yaml`. also it is well described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/configuration/#configure-neo4j-in-kubernetes).

Comment: i am in kubernetes approch, so i have not acess to this file

Comment: @fredricksonbande Once again, I'm not sure how did you achieve the Kubernetes approach. e.g. if you were using `Neo4j Helm` instead of `neo4j.conf` you will have `values.yaml`  You can read more about it here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/configuration/#configure-neo4j-in-kubernetes

Comment: thanks, i will use helm instead kubectl to install neo4j. i will give feedback.